# NUnit 3: no exception of the exact type was thrown?

Tags: c#, nunit

How can I assert that **no** exception of the **exact** type was thrown in my code?

Both

```
Assert.That(testDelegate, Throws.Nothing); // any type of an exception was not thrown
```

and

```
Assert.That(testDelegate, Throws.InstanceOf<ExactException>()); // an exception of needed type was thrown
```

are not correct way here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NUnit does not have a constraint that says something like `Does.Not.Throw.TypeOf<ExactException>()` and passes for/ignores other exceptions. It is a fairly rare use case to test that a method does not throw a specific exception, but pass if any other exception is thrown. To me, it is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), but if you really want to do it, you can get the behavior you want like this,

```
[Test]
public void DoesNotThrowSpecificException()
{
    try
    {
        MethodThatShouldntThrowExactException(); // But may throw any other exception
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.That(ex, Is.Not.TypeOf(typeof(ExactException)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am inclined to consider that my idea is as code smell now. And I just use `Assert.That(testDelegate, Throws.Nothing);`. But thank for your answer

Comment: Yeah, in my case, I want to say DoesNotThrow<InvalidOperationException>in order to document what the original bug was. If it's another exception, then that's a separate issue... as long as there's not this type, then this test should pass.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want

```
Assert.That(testDelegate, Throws.TypeOf<ExactException>());
```

`InstanceOf` means "of the exact type or a derived type" - just like how `is` works. We use `TypeOf` to mean it must be the exact type. It creates an `ExactTypeConstraint`.

OTOH, if you want to make a negative test (that it does **not** throw `ExactException`) then you can't use the fluent syntax. You **could** specify the constraint expression directly, like this...

```
Assert.That(testDelegate, 
    new NotConstraint(
        new ThrowsConstraint(
            new ExactTypeConstraint(typeof(ExactException)))));
```

I'm **not** recommending that, but it's available. I'd use Rob's workaround if I had to do this, but I'd also question **why** I was doing it and hopefully find a way to avoid a situation where any exception **except** a certain one is OK.

Comment: Sorry, probably I said not clear, but the idea was to test a method does not throw a specific exception (see @Rob Prouse answer)

Comment: I misunderstood then. Added alternate workaround to answer.